# Custom Widget - How to correctly provide widget with args

Tags: django, forms, widget

How do I correctly provide a custom widget with attrs? The call `print attrs` only outputs this:

```
attrs in LockFlagWidget are:
{'id': u'id_lockedFlag'}
```

whereas I would expect this:

```
attrs in LockFlagWidget are:
{'id': u'id_lockedFlag', 'size': u'80}
```

I wrote a custom widget like this:

```
class LockFlagWidget(forms.widgets.Widget):

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value is None:
                value = ''
        print "attrs in LockFlagWidget are:"
        print attrs
        staticURL = getattr(settings, 'STATIC_URL')

        if value != '':
            if value == True:
                return mark_safe(u"<img src=\"" + staticURL +
                                 "lock/img/lock_closed.ico\"/>"
                                 + "<span> - Is locked</span>")
            else:
                return mark_safe(u"<img src=\"" + staticURL +
                                 "lock/img/lock_open.ico\"/>"
                                 + "<span> - Is not locked</span>")
```

Now I m using the widget in a form like this:

```
class LockForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LockForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['lockedFlag'].widget = LockFlagWidget(attrs={'size':'80'})
```

`MyModel` looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    lockedFlag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to my like the attributes that are being passed into your render method are the attributes from the field not the widget, try to change your print statement to `print self.attrs`, that will pick up the attributes that you passed into the constructor of your widget. Hope that makes sense?